# converting spring boot jar to war

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I developed a spring boot project. Now my requirement is to convert the jar package into war.
 1. I converted the jar into war. After converting, I deployed the war into the tomcat server and tried to hit the web service.

```
@EnableAsync
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.app.sensiple")
public class SensipleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SensipleApplication.class);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SensipleApplication.class, args);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    String test() {
        return "This is test and it's Working fine!";
    }
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>snservice</artifactId>
    <version>443-async</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>sensiple</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>               
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

UrL: localhost:8080/snservice/test

The above url is working fine.

2. My application contains different packages like Controller, Service and Repo. I have added the screenshot of my project structure.
   [image: Scrren shot Project structure]
3. The issue is i can't able to hit the services in controller package. Do i need to configure dispatcher Servlet for this???? . Anybody please help me out?

Comment: You don't need `@ComponentScan` nor `@EnableAutoConfiguration` as that is already implied by `@SpringBoot`. Your application will automatically detect everything in the sub packages. What did you exactly change in your `pom.xml` and have you followed [the steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) as outlined in the reference guide. (You still need the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency should be scoped with `provided.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but i have done all the steps, still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: i have also attached my pom.xml, please check it once.

Comment: How are you calling the application when deployed? The url will be different then when running locally. Unless you configured it to run on the same url. But else the `/snservice` should be replaced by `/<name-of-war>` something like `/snservice-443-async` as it will be deployed (by default) on the url with the same name as the archive).

Comment: Thank you so much, I used that war name in Url, now it's fine.It is working now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using maven you can indicate it in pom.xml packaging

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- ... -->
        </dependencies>
```

Next you need to provide a SpringBootServletInitializer subclass and override its configure method.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for support, but i still have the same issue, 404. Can't able to hit the services in controller package. i have also added the pom.xml. please check it once.

Comment: Hi @VijayS, try add SpringBootServletInitializer

Comment: Same issues for me too. I have tried all solutions in SO but nothing changed. Control is coming to the class but only .jsp file is not rendering. Please Help Me any one.

Answer (score 0):

We need 3 steps for convert JAR to WAR in Spring Boot:

1. Change packaging to war
2. Marked the embedded tomcat as provided.
3. Extends SpringBootServletInitializer and override the configure()
   method.

I have converted jar to war in spring boot by using given below website (Explained step by step).

https://tecmentor.in/spring-boot/convert-jar-to-war-in-spring-boot/

Comment: What is the difference from @Rupendra Sharma answer? Plagiarism

Comment: The link gives a 404 error page.